# Implicit function Theorem - Regular Points

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to understand the relation beetween Implicit Theorem and Singular and Regular points. I searched the internet but didn't find much about this topic. For example, this exercise, how can I solve it? $$Let \ \ f_\lambda=(x^2+y^2-z^2,x+y+z\lambda) \ be \ a \ function\ , \\\ Determinate \ all \ \lambda \in \mathbb{R} \ so\ that \ (1,0) \ is\ a \ regular \ point\ of \ f_\lambda.
$$

Thanks for the help, if someone finds some tips would be great.

Comment: I think you want $(1,0)$ to be a regular *value*, not a regular *point*. Do you know the definition of a regular point? Your function is a map $\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^2$, so for a point $p\in\mathbb{R}^3$ to be regular we need $Df_p$ to have rank 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As symplectomorphic has remarked in his comment we want that $(1,0)$ is a *regular value* of $f_\lambda$, i.e., that $df_\lambda(p)$ has rank $2$ at all $p\in{\mathbb R}^3$ with $f_\lambda(p)=(1,0)$. One computes
$$df_\lambda(x,y,z)=\left[\matrix{2x &2y &-2z\cr 1&1&\lambda\cr}\right]\ .$$
The rank of this matrix is $<2$ iff
$$\lambda y+z=0\quad\wedge\quad  \lambda x+z=0\quad \wedge\quad x=y\ ,$$
or, iff
$$y=x\quad\wedge\quad z=-\lambda x\ .$$
The question now is: For which values $\lambda$ are there points $p:=(x,x,-\lambda x)$ such that
$f_\lambda(p)=(1,0)$? One computes
$$f_\lambda(p)=(2x^2-\lambda^2 x^2, 2x-\lambda^2 x)\ .$$
The condition $(2-\lambda^2)x=0$ implies that $(2-\lambda^2)x^2=0$ as well. From this we conclude that there are no such points $p$, whatever $\lambda$, i.e., that $(1,0)$ is a regular value of $f_\lambda$ for all $\lambda\in{\mathbb R}$.

Comment: Geometrically, one intersects a hyperboloid with one sheet with a plane that can't be the tangent plane at any point on the hyperboloid. Such an intersection is necessarily transversal.

Comment: Really thanks. I understand everything, but just one thing. U said that  $$Df_\lambda$$ has to have rank 2, but that happens because this is a function $$\mathbb{R}^3$$ to $$\mathbb{R}^n$$ , where $$n$$ is 2 right? The rank depends on the $$n$$ ?

Comment: Given $f_\lambda :\>{\mathbb R}^3\to{\mathbb R}^2$ one has ${\rm rank}\bigl(df_\lambda(p)\bigr)\leq2$ at all points. The map is *singular* at a point $p$ if ${\rm rank}\bigl(df_\lambda(p)\bigr)<2$.